# Increasing a for loop integer j by i in Java

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, sieve

I want to turn this "pseudocode" into something that works in Java and I'm having trouble

```
for j = i², i²+i, i²+2i, ..., not exceeding n:
```

Would this be correct?

```
for (int j = i*i; j < n; j++) {
    //other code here that does the operation:
    isPrime[j] = false;
    j = j+i;
}
```

Comment: Do you know what the parts of a `for` loop do? You can just change the increment…

Comment: Yes I understand the parts of a for loop. I'm having a conceptual problem understanding what to do. Can you maybe help explain what the fix would be in the incrementing part of the for loop?

Comment: Could you be more specific on the algorithm? You actually increment j twice in your loop. Once in the loop declaration and then at the the end of your loop.

Comment: So you need j to be: i², i²+i, i²+2*i ? Seems that your real counter is k, where k is right here: i²+k*i

Comment: Got it, thanks. Still something in my overall code is not working. Guess I'll have to figure that out instead. Thanks everyone!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on[codereview.se].

Answer (score 4):

What you want is this:

```
for (int j = i * i; j < n; j += i)
{
   isPrime[j] = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first problem I see is that you are incrementing j twice. Once in the declaration and again at the end of the loop. Have you tried:

```
for (int j = i*i; j < n; j+=i) {
    //other code here that does the operation:
    isPrime[j] = false;
}
```